# PHP create "short" unique ID without followup pattern

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to create unique ID's which don't have a followup pattern in some way like uniqid() does.

I have trhought about randomizing of course but this makes a uniqid() less unique as it might need to rehash after detecting where uniqid() does a sleep at that moment.

I'm also not sure what happens when I insert a uniqid() into a DB and I would do mutiple and it gets a duplicate when there are mutliple processes running. Will the insert just fail or does uniqid() detects it in time on the same system ?

Length is also an issue of course. You don't want 65 character userID's but for files this would be no issue next to an ai_id.

So what would be my best bet ? I have google a lot about it and everyone has another reeason why this/that is better. uniqid() helps me great it's just too much pattern based which I would like to avoid.

Comment: so.. what's the problem with IDs? Why are you afraid? Even Facebook uses numeric IDs.. which is the simplest pattern you may have

Comment: Actually 2:

Simply being able to see how much items are there, you can reference quite easy. As in Facebook it doesn't matter, there are so many users that 10-20 less is no problem. In other businesses this matters.

For filenaming your can see grouping

Comment: try this code echo sprintf('%04X%02X', mt_rand(0, 65535),mt_rand(0, 65535));

Comment: @ArjanShrestha TBH I think that is a losing battle, 32 bits of entropy will start collisions in 10-20 thousand generations, even if you use a CSRNG.